# Is it possible that $L=NP$?

Tags: complexity-theory

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_(complexity)) and other sources, the question whether $L=P$ is an open problem, and of course everyone is familiar with the problem of whether $P=NP$. However, I found absolutely no information online regarding a possible equality between $L$ and $NP$.

Such an equality doesn't directly violate the space-hierarchy theorem or the time-hierarchy theorem, and so I don't have any idea how to disprove it.

Comment: Have you checked the [complexity zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo)?

Comment: A quick skim of the sections for $L$ and $NP there doesn't answer my question, and in general I think it is elementary enough to deserve its own cs.stackexhange. I did find some somewhat relevant and answered questions in cs.theory, but they were a lot more complicated and with a broader scope.

Comment: It's an open question: https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/taking-passes-at-np-versus-l/

Comment: See also [47522 (If P=NP, then is L=NL?)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/47522/if-mathbfp-mathbfnp-then-is-mathbfl-mathbfnl)

Comment: The only thing we know is [$\text{L} \subsetneq \text{PSPACE}$](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32218/l-p-pspace-vs-p-np).

Comment: @PålGD That's stronger than David's answer -- maybe you want to add something there? Should we close this here as duplicate then?

Comment: @DeanGurvitz I find it hard to navigate the zoo myself, just thought to point you there. Afaik it reflects the current state of research so if a relation isn't on there, it's most likely unknown.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I do think that an explicit answer to this question would be helpful, and unfortunately isn't a part of David's answer on the linked cs.stackexchange post.

Comment: Okay, I made my links into a short answer.  I agree that the question per se is not a duplicate, but the answer exists on stackexchange.  But then again, for which question is that not the case?

Comment: @PålGD Not only "for which question is that not the case?", but also the scope/level of the other questions linked is much broader/higher, and I sincerely think that this post has a right to exist merely because it is a relatively basic and focused question whose answer is hard to find otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question whether $L = NP$ is an open problem [1], so yes, it is possible.  However, it is considered unlikely, or in other words, most *believe* that $L \subsetneq P \subsetneq NP \subsetneq PSPACE$, but we only *know* that $L \subsetneq PSPACE$ [2, 3].

References:

- [1] [Taking Passes at NP Versus L — Gödel's Lost Letter and P=NP](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/taking-passes-at-np-versus-l/)
- [2] [L/P/PSpace vs P/NP — cstheory.stackexchange.com](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32218/l-p-pspace-vs-p-np)
- [3] [If P=NP, then is L=NL? — cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/47522/if-mathbfp-mathbfnp-then-is-mathbfl-mathbfnl)